# Show different suffix in Google Piechart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, pie-chart, google-pie-chart

I have a piechart showing the result the **total bandwidth** of `uplink/downlink`.

Right now, they suffix is GB.

[image]

I struggling trying to display their suffix different. 
Example,

- Downlink in `GB`
- Uplink in `KB`.

---

I have

```
<script>

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  console.log(color['downlink']);

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Bandwith'],
    ['Downlink', ({{$t_down_bytes}})],
    ['Uplink', ({{$t_up_bytes}})]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: 'buttom',
    pieSliceText: 'value', // text | none
    title: 'Total Bandwith Usage',
    colors: [color['downlink'], color['uplink']],
    width:'100%',
    height: 400,
    slices: {
      1: {offset: 0.1}
    },

  };

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits:2,
    suffix: ' GB'
  });

  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('private'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

</script>
```

I can someone can shed some light on this.

Any hints / suggestions on this will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is just doing it yourself: ([Correct way to convert size in bytes to KB, MB, GB in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900485/correct-way-to-convert-size-in-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-in-javascript) might help)

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Bandwith'],
      ['Downlink', {v:6.4672328, f:"6.46 GB"}],
      ['Uplink', {v:9.40213213, f:"9.40 KB"}]
    ]);
```

Note that v is the "real" value google uses to draw and f is the formatted value it will show

If you want to keep your google formatter, another way is to add this line after your `formatter.format(data, 1);`

```
data.setFormattedValue(1,1,data.getFormattedValue(1,1).replace("GB","KB"))
```

Which sets the formattedValue of row 1, column 1

**Update** taking into account you want to use a mix of both:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Bandwith'],
  ['Downlink', $t_down_bytes],
  ['Uplink', $t_up_bytes],
 ]);

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits:2
});

formatter.format(data, 1);

data.setFormattedValue(0,1,data.getFormattedValue(0,1) + ' {{$t_down_bytes_suffix}}')

data.setFormattedValue(1,1,data.getFormattedValue(1,1) + ' {{$t_up_bytes_suffix}}')
```

For more info on `setFormattedValue` and `getFormattedValue` check

[Google Datatable Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#DataTable_setFormattedValue)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it now.

Comment: What is this `replace("GB","KB")` do ?

Comment: Well, `formatter.format(data, 1);` sets your formattedValue of your uplink value to '9.40 GB', so I get that value with `data.getFormattedValue(1,1)` and then replace the 'GB' with 'KB'

Comment: What if I have `MB`, or `B` ?

Comment: I'm afraid that the `replace()` won't be the solution.

Comment: Then I recommend the first solution, set it yourself according to your need on each cell

Comment: Sure, I'll use that then.

Comment: Do you mind take a quick look to my updated code ? I followed your instruction, and still couldn't get the suffix to display.

Comment: Yeah you need to remove the formatter, if not google formatter is overriding the custom values that you set

Comment: I still want to keep my `fractionDigits:2`, the rest I can ditch it.

Comment: I update my post showing all the possible try/result that I did/got.

Comment: Have updated my answer. Also, just adding your latest try is enough, no need to go over all of them

Comment: Okay. I'll fix my post.

Comment: Got it. You may want to explain this `data.setFormattedValue(0,1,data.getFormattedValue(0,1)` . If you want. Thanks for your help mate. :)