# React native: how to get file size, mime type and extension?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I know [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) and [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob), but I'm missing simple helper functions like `getFileInfo(file)`.

**Desired pseudo code:**

```
let fileInfo = getFileInfo('path/to/my/file.txt');
console.log('file size: ' + fileInfo.size);
console.log('mime type: ' + fileInfo.type);
console.log('extension: ' + fileInfo.extension);
```

What's the proper way to get the file size, mime type and extension?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having the same question, did you find any solution?

Comment: @dccarmo Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: @dccarmo Check the new answer, maybe it works for you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With **react-native-fetch-blob**, you can get the file size with the code below:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(PATH_OF_THE_TARGET)
.then((stats) => {})
.catch((err) => {})
```

The response **stats** contains the following info:

```
{
     // file name
     filename : 'foo.png',
     // folder of the file or the folder itself
     path : '/path/to/the/file/without/file/name/',
     // size, in bytes
     size : 4901,
     // `file` or `directory`
     type : 'file',
     // last modified timestamp
     lastModified : 141323298
}
```

Source: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#user-content-statpathstringpromisernfetchblobstat

Comment: what about the mime type?

Answer (score 14):

In `react-native-fs` you can use the `stat` method (to get the file size)

```
import { stat } from 'react-native-fs';

...

const statResult = await stat('path/to/my/file.txt');
console.log('file size: ' + statResult.size);
```

Comment: What about the file's mime-type ?

Answer (score 9):

**File size:** This answer suits best with new CRNA client. Use [File System](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem) from Expo.

```
// import {FileSystem} from expo // Original Post
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system' // Updated based on docs

getFileSize = async fileUri => {
   let fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(fileUri);
   return fileInfo.size;
 };
```

Comment: it works, but should import like this  
"import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';"

Answer (score 2):

You can get data about the blob with react-native-fetch-blob and use react-native-mime-types to get the extension

```
const res = yield RNFetchBlob.config({fileCache: false}).fetch('GET', url, {})
const blob =  yield res.blob().then((blob) => {
    mimetype.extension(blob.type)
  }
)
```

Comment: What if someone spoof the extension?  Is there a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

To getting **file size** using react-native-fetch-blob i used the following code.

**Its only suitable for small size files. If you have large size files try with some other below answers**

For that u need to install [base-64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64)

```
var base64 = require('base-64');
RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(filePath, 'base64')
    .then((data) => {
        var decodedData = base64.decode(data);
        var bytes=decodedData.length;
        if(bytes < 1024) console.log(bytes + " Bytes");
        else if(bytes < 1048576) console.log("KB:"+(bytes / 1024).toFixed(3) + " KB");
        else if(bytes < 1073741824) console.log("MB:"+(bytes / 1048576).toFixed(2) + " MB");
        else console.log((bytes / 1073741824).toFixed(3) + " GB");
    })
```

Explanation:

1. The above code decode the base64 data to string like atob().
2. Next finding length of string
3. From that value i have to calculate the file size.

If the file is too large use **RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream** method instead of RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile

I am getting bytes calculation from [SO convert size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900485/correct-way-to-convert-size-in-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-in-javascript)

The code may be too long to calculate file size. If anyone found easiest way guide me

Comment: Don't use this, it will crash the app with any remotely large files. Use @mfekim's answer instead: `const { size } = await RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(PATH_OF_THE_TARGET)`