# Convert Bytes to GB using javascriot and getting values from the sum of a column in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am getting the sum of the values from a column of my ng-repeat. I am getting it already but the value is in bytes. I need to convert it directly to GB in order for me to use in on my other opertion. My code is like this. At first I am getting the sum of my column in ng-repeat like this:

```
$scope.getTotal = function(type) {

        var totalStorage = $scope.totalStorage;

        var usedtotal = 0;
        var total =0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.adList.length; i++){
           var product = $scope.adList[i];
           total += JSON.parse(product.size );
       }
```

and after the for loop, i am converting the value, I am using this code but it only converts the value to MB.

```
var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
           if (total == 0) return '0 Byte';
           var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(total) / Math.log(1024)));
           return Math.round(total / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];


    return total;
    };
```

I am also quite not sure about the conversion because the sum I have is 30150489 bytes and when using this code, it converts to 29MB not 30.15MB. and I need to convert this directly to GB. How can I do that?

Comment: Because 30150489 bytes is actually 28.75 MB not 30.15 MB. Just like 10000 bytes is 9.77 KB not 10 KB (in binary).

Comment: ow, okay @fuzz how can I convert it to GB then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900485/correct-way-to-convert-size-in-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-in-javascript

Comment: `parseInt(Math.floor` - seems like overkill

Comment: `Math.round(total / Math.pow(1024, i), 2)` ... what makes you think Math.round takes a second argument?

Comment: to convert ANY number to GB ... divide by it by `1073741824`