# Merge or Use instance and Native render make no difference with Chrome plus Integrated Graphics Card

Tags: google-chrome, optimization, webgl, instance

With the help of some other people here,
I found that when use the ThreeJS to render stuff
no matter if i just render in native drawcalls or merge them to render once, or use instance rendering,
the FPS is almost that same, some time the native mode is faster.

The graphics card I use is Inter（R） HD Graphics 630(desktop) and  Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics 655(macbook pro)

If I tested on Discrete graphics then i can see the difference, which merged > instance > native.

If I use the same machine + firefox, then I can see the FPS difference, So I can sure it's Chromes' issue.

However the key problems is, although the FPS in chromes is faster than firefox.
So I suppose it's not a bug, bug chrome did something with Integrated Graphics Card inside but I can not understand.

If merge or instance can not make a big difference, then how can we optimize the rendering speed with Chrome.

Any help?
Thanks a lot
Check the link here for the question:
[Comparing FPS between instance and merge drawcall and native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828683/comparing-fps-between-instance-and-merge-drawcall-and-native/59836250#59836250)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing FPS between instance and merge drawcall and native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828683/comparing-fps-between-instance-and-merge-drawcall-and-native)

Comment: this is just what i asked before, so the guessing there seems did not answer why this works for firefox but not working for chrome -_-!!!