# rounding a number so it will not be 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

hi in our app we show data in GB but right now I have a really small number in bites.
how can I round up my number?
example:
I have 0.000065gb but I really want to see 0.01gb. is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Why not show Mb, b as appropriate to the file size? SOmething like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900485/correct-way-to-convert-size-in-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-in-javascript

Comment: because we show this number in the graph also. i don't want to refactor whole app just so i can see Mb or bite

Comment: `if (size < 0.01) size = 0.01;`  FYI, you don't have to "refactor the whole app" to change one display value. That's a little exaggerated to say that.

Answer (score 2):

Right before displaying the value, you can put the value in another variable and then do something like this with it:

```
if (size < 0.01) size = 0.01;       // set minimum display size
```

Or, if `0` is a legit value, so you only want to round-up non-zero things, then:

```
if (size !== 0 && size < 0.01) size = 0.01;       // set minimum display size
```

Answer (score 0):

dividing by the precision you want to round by would work as well and would allow you to vary the precision a bit too. I found a link to an old stack overflow thread

basically something like this

```
Math.round( yourNumber * 100 ) / 100
```

He also uses Number.EPSILON since his precision specifications seem to get really close to 0.

[old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Edit: put * in twice second should be /