# how to calculate upload speed in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, xmlhttprequest

i'm working on a django website and i have a view where the user is able to upload videos and i need to add a button for the user so he can make a short test for his upload speed
after a lot of research i found this script but it seems that it's not working and i could not know why

```
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var startTime, endTime;
var myData = "d="; // the raw data you will send
for(var i = 0 ; i < 1022 ; i++) //if you want to send 1 kb (2 + 1022 bytes = 1024b = 1kb). change it the way you want
{
    myData += "k"; // add one byte of data;
}

http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", myData .length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        ShowData();
    }
}
startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
http.send(myData);

function ShowData()
{
    var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    var bitsLoaded = myData * 8;
    var speedMbps = ((bitsLoaded / duration) / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);
    alert("Speed: " + speedMbps + " Mbps");
}
```

so is there any simple method for calculating the upload speed of the user or any fix for this script

Answer (score 2):

Old post but saw no solution and I was wanting to calculate upload speeds as well. Here is my solution.

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
var chunk = 0;

http.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
    if (elengthComputable){
        // bytes transferred since last update
        bytes = e.loaded - chunk;
        chunk = e.loaded;
        
        // Get number of seconds since last update
        ms = new Date().getTime();
        elapsed = (ms - timestamp) / 1000.0
        timestamp = ms;
        
        // Divide by elapsed time to get bytes per second
        bps = bytes / elapsed;
        
        // Output upload speed
        console.log("Speed: " + formatBytes(bps)+"/s");
        
    }
}, false);
```

The formatBytes() function I use is provided on this page:
[Correct way to convert size in bytes to KB, MB, GB in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900485/correct-way-to-convert-size-in-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `progress` event of the [`upload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload) property

```
http.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
    console.log(e.loaded + ' uploaded out of ' + e.total);
    // do your calculations here
}, false);
```