# javascript drop and drag, than display image information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**issue:** How can I get image name, size, ext and display in `'imgDetail'` div

update - filename is print as Name: `${file.name}` rather than file name

drag and drop file html button

```
<div id="dropZone" style="width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: red"></div>
```

display image information

```
<div id="imgDetail"></div>
```

drag and drop script

```
<script>
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');
    var detailsDiv = document.querySelector('#imgDetail');

    // Optional.   Show the copy icon when dragging over.  Seems to only work for chrome.
    dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    });

    // Get file data on drop
      dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('dropZone').classList.remove("hoverActive");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = e.dataTransfer.files; // get all files
    Object.values(files).forEach((file) => { //loop though all files
        if (file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e2) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = e2.target.result;
                img.width = 100;
                img.height = 100;
                detailsDiv.innerHTML += '<p>Size: ${bytesToSize(file.size)}</p>';
                //display image 
                var div = document.getElementById('imageHold')
                div.appendChild(img);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }// end of if
    });// end of for
});


function bytesToSize(bytes) {
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
    if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
    var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
    return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Use `backticks` instead of  `single quotes` more about [how to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the image name or size in a div just use the property innerHTML and bytesToSize function to format the file size.

```js
var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');
var details = document.querySelector('#imgDetail');

dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
});

dropZone.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  details.innerHTML = '';
  var files = e.dataTransfer.files;

  Object.values(files).forEach((file) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      details.innerHTML += `
        <p>Name: ${file.name}<p>
        <p>Size: ${bytesToSize(file.size)}</p>
        <img src="${reader.result}" alt="${file.name}">`;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});

function bytesToSize(bytes) {
  var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
  if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
  var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
  return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropZone" style="width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: red"></div>
<div id="imgDetail"></div>
```

Comment: Yo can check more about [correct way to convert size in bytes to KB, MB, GB in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900485/correct-way-to-convert-size-in-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-in-javascript).

Comment: that weird, file name is printing '${file.name}' i think i missed something

Comment: try using `Object.values(files).forEach((file)` instead of `for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++)`