# Javascript - How to Transform MiB to GB

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I am trying to convert values from my API response, where I get the values in MiB.
I need to convert these MiB values to GB to put the available server memory size in my graph, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Can you help me? I am a beginner in Angular.

My Code:

```
  this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: this.serverName,
            datasets: [
              {
                data: this.serverMemory,
                borderColor: 'transparent',
                label: 'Full Memory',
                backgroundColor: '#007bff',
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderRadius: 10,
              },
              {
                data: this.serverMemoryUnused,
                borderColor: 'transparent',
                label: 'Memory Unused',
                backgroundColor: '#e3ebf6',
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderRadius: 10,
              },
            ],
          },

          options: {
            scales: {
              x: {
                display: true,
              },
              y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                  callback: (label: any) => `${label * (1048576 / 1000000000)} GB`
                   
                },
                grid: {
                  display: false
                }
              },



            }
          }
        });
```

My API is returning this: "4096000"

However, when passing this value to the function it returns all values as a float, I would like only 2 decimal places.

The function is returning this

```
4718.592000000001 GB
4194.304 GB
3670.016 GB
```

[Result from function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Kel.png)

I would like something like:

```
4.59 GB
4.19 GB
3.67 GB
2.61 GB
10 GB
20 GB
30 GB
```

Comment: Use [`.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format your number into a string with two decimal places. If you want to conditionally format floats and not integers, you can do `Number.isInteger(num) ? num : num.toFixed(2)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900485/correct-way-to-convert-size-in-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-in-javascript

Comment: @Terry

Sorry, I didn't understand this topic very well, when I access the link and do as in the examples cited, my result shows up as MB and direferent values, not GB.

I tried it this way and now it is returning:
4.719 GB
4.194 GB

callback: (label: any) => `${Math.round((label * 1048576) / 1000000000).toLocaleString('decimal')} GB`

Do you know how I can leave only 4.71 or 4.7 GB? I tried using toFixed but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the example values of `label`? And how they should look like after formatting? Most of the code in your question can be safely removed since they don’t condemn the label formatting at all.

Comment: @Terry

My API returns exactly this number: 4096000 so the label is 4096000

I would like a result like:

4.5 GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MiB** = 1,024 * 1,024 Bytes
**GB** = 1,000 * 1,000 * 1,000 Bytes

Therefore you first have to multply your value by 1,024^2 and after that divide it by 1,000^3.

Your code should be something like this: `(label * 1048576) / 1000000000` (yes, that is equivalent to your calculation).

Anyway, I guess the return value of your API is not in MiB, because the result of the calculation is 3 dimension to large.

Comment: HI Gregor,
I tried it this way and now it is returning: 4.719 GB 4.194 GB callback: (label: any) => ${Math.round((label * 1048576) / 1000000000).toLocaleString('decimal')} GB Do you know how I can leave only 4.71 or 4.7 GB?

Comment: As the other commenters already said: `(4.719).toFixed(1)` is your friend and should solve your problems.